# Problemas de Certificado Intel Emulator Accelerator en Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, windows

Buenas chicos, antes de nada decir que soy nuevo en esta web y fan de la misma.
Os comento, he adquirido un nuevo ordenador: procesador i7 6700k y placa base Asus H170, una bestia.

Pues resulta que al instalar el sistema operativo de nuevo y ya con la actualización de aniversario de windows a la hora de instalar android studio apareció un problema durante la instalación del citado plugin que te ayuda a hacer funcionar el emulador. Mostrando dos errores, el de que al parecer no está en las BIOS la virtualización activada (cosa que hice posteriormente) y luego que el certificado de instalación de HAXM_Driver no está firmado. Y aquí es cuando yo digo ¿Hola?

Terminando: Realicé el inicio desde Configuración / Actualización y Seguridad / Recuperación / Reiniciar Ahora / F7 (Una vez Reiniciado) y arranca de nuevo el sistema con el ajuste de seguridad que comprueba los certificados deshabilitado. Pues bien, esto en el 80% de las ocasiones no me funcionó, seguía apareciendo el mismo problema al tratar de instalar el plugin para el emulador. Aunque si es cierto que he conseguido hacer funcionar el emulador un par de veces, luego, al siguiente reinicio o apagado y encendido vuelve otra vez a salirme el famoso mensaje de:

> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.

Como si tuviera desactivado la virtualización cosa que no toco y seguía activado en las BIOS. Pero vaya estoy completamente seguro que la causa es el certificado. ¿Alguien le ha pasado este error? ¿Tenéis idea de solucionarlo por otros medios?

Comment: Tal vez tu pregunta no esté relacionada con este sitio. El hecho que hayas detectado el problema durante la instalación del Android Studio, no lo convierte en tópico; el problema al parecer sigue estando en el hardware. Hay dos comunidades en la red de SO en donde tal vez te puedan ayudar: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) y [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: la siguiente es una URL que explica sobre HAXM ---------- https://software.intel.com/es-es/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows ----------
Lastimosamente está en inglés, pero espero que pueda ayudarte en lo que preguntas.

Comment: @toledano esos sitios no tienen su símil en español, por lo que está bien aceptar la pregunta **aquí**.